# Get information from website for Android

Tags: java, android

I want to make an application that compare pizza prices. To do that I have to go to the actual site and enter and search. How can I display the prices WITHOUT the user seeing the actions of going to the website and entering a search. Would I use a WebView and a WebViewClient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use [HttpClient](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) to do the web calls in the background.  You would only use WebView to display webpages to the user.